# Python. Error con comando pip install -r requirement.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

Tengo que instalar unas dependencias para un proyecto, estas están en un fichero llamado `requirements.txt`

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
./PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
absl-py==0.9.0
astor==0.8.1
audioread==2.1.8
cachetools==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
cython==0.27.3
decorator==4.4.1
gast==0.2.2
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-auth==1.11.0
google-pasta==0.1.8
grpcio==1.27.1
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.8
imageio==2.6.1
joblib==0.14.1
keras-applications==1.0.8
keras-preprocessing==1.1.0
keras==2.3.1
kiwisolver==1.1.0
librosa==0.7.2
llvmlite==0.31.0
markdown==3.2
matplotlib==3.1.3
mouseinfo==0.1.2
networkx==2.4
numba==0.48.0
numpy==1.18.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
opt-einsum==3.1.0
pandas==1.0.1
pillow==7.0.0
protobuf==3.11.3
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyautogui==0.9.48
pycparser==2.19
pygetwindow==0.0.8
pymsgbox==1.0.7
pypandoc==1.4
pyparsing==2.4.6
pyperclip==1.7.0
pyrect==0.1.4
pyscreeze==0.1.26
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytweening==1.0.3
pytz==2019.3
pywavelets==1.1.1
pyyaml==5.3
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests==2.22.0
resampy==0.2.2
rsa==4.0
scikit-image==0.16.2
scikit-learn==0.22.1
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
soundfile==0.10.3.post1
tensorboard==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
tensorflow==2.1.0
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.25.8
werkzeug==1.0.0
wheel==0.34.2 ; python_version >= '3'
winshell==0.6
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Ejecuto el comando : `pip install -r requirements.txt` y me arroja el siguiente **error:**

```
C:\...>pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Mi versión de Python es: `3.9.2`.

Aclarar que el fichero que intenta abrir en `requirement.txt` existe en el directorio.

Comment: en la segunda línea de tu archivo txt aparece `./PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` y está siendo reportada en el mensaje de error que muestras.

Comment: @quevedo ya ya, pero no entiendo porque me dice dice ese error.

Answer (score 1):

El error te dice que el `.whl` no funciona en esa plataforma.

En concreto estás usando un `.whl` para `cp37`, `cp37` significa Python 3.7 y tu versión de Python es 3.9.2 de ahí el error que te dice:

> not a supported wheel on this platform.

Como se puede ver en [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#history) la última versión de este paquete salió en marzo de 2017, por lo que te será imposible encontrar un paquete en la versión 3.9. A partir de aquí tienes dos soluciones:

1. **Crearte un entorno con Python 3.7** e instalar el paquete (recomendado)
2. **Utilizar otra librería de audio** más actualizada, por ejemplo [librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html). Tienes que considerar que al tomar esta opción, **vas a tener que modificar el código.**

### Extra

Un archivo `.whl` es el formato estandar por Python para construir paquetes.